# Custom parameters in purchase event in GA4

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

Is it possible to send custom parameters to GA4 inside a purchase event like the below:

Specifically, will I be able to see the custom parameter data inside GA4?

```
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
dataLayer.push({ ecommerce: null }); 
dataLayer.push({
  event: "purchase",
  ecommerce: {
      transaction_id: "T_12345", 
      value: 25.00,
      tax: 5,
      currency: "GBP",
      lines_ordered: 2, // custom parameter
      direct_debit: 1, // custom parameter
      coupon: "SUMMER_SALE",
      items: [
       {
      item_name: "Product 1", 
      item_category: "Type A", 
      discount: 2.00,
      }]
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, however, there are a few things to keep in mind and a few steps you need to perform to see the data in GA4 UI

- You must not add any custom parameters inside the `items[]` array. This should be according to Google's standard requirements.
- For the parameters you have mentioned in your post, you need to create variables in GTM to get their value, and then pass them with each event separately. You need to name the parameters in the event (purchase in your case) GTM tag
- Then you need to go into GA4 UI and map the parameters with custom dimensions. Once done, you should be able to see the parameters.